# How to get all files from a directory

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a directory, having more than two files. i need to get all files for attaching to PHP mail function. So i need a php function to get all files from the directory. anybody could you please help me to give an idea to get a result.

thank you.

Comment: google  'php get dir contents'

Comment: use glob() funtion, http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: this question is too broad; did you try anything that may have failed you?

Answer (score 0):

Use glob() function, you will get all folders and files in current directory

```
foreach(glob('*') as $files){
    echo "<br />".$files;
}
```

for more info, please visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

for specific file extension e.g. `.php`, you can use `glob('*.php')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [**scandir()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function to list the files. So you can loop to add the files

```
<?php
$directory = '/path/to/my/directory';
// Eliminate folder "." and ".."
$files = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));

?>
```

I recommend you to use [PHPMailer](http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for send emails.

```
<?php
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );
foreach($files as $file):
    $email->AddAttachment( $file );
endforeach;
return $email->Send();
```